# Saving images on heroku DB versus Amazon S3: Pros Cons?

Tags: database, image, heroku, amazon-s3

Ive searched everywhere on the internet for a comparison of saving images in a Heroku PG-SQL db versus saving them on Amazon S3. Im currently trying to make a design decision. However, this is the first time Im writing a web app. So far this is what I know to make the decision:

1. Saving images on DB slows the performance of the app
2. Saving images on Db is expensive versus the filesystem
3. You cannot access the file system in Heroku
4. You can save images in Amazon S3 for a very cheap rate
5. Images stored on Amazon S3 cannot be processed before saving if they donot pass     through the application on Heroku
6. Retrieving and saving images on Amazon S3 costs money for each call
7. If the browser is retrieving an object that has an image, then the browser makes 2     requests per object, 1 for the data from heroku and another from S3 for the image. This can   be problematic since the browser can only make certain >m.unt of requests per unit time.
8. Saving images on DB if the images are small in size doesnt deteriorate performance a lot.
9. Deleting images from Database can cause fragmentation

These are the fact I know about the topic. As things stand right now, Im leaning towards saving images in the Heroku DB. Since they are mostly thumbnails/small images and their size is less that 250MB

I was wondering if someone could let me know if these facts are erroneous or if there are other consideration I need to make in making this design decision.

Also, I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to some good discussions on the web on this topic. I couldn't find any that exactly were on this discusssion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save them on S3. Performance wise, it's leagues ahead of storing on a database - if you store on a database, the request has to go through your web application, then make a DB request (or hit varnish right away, but that is true in any case). Further, unless you have a lot of dynos, this means that users are only be going to getting images one at a time (thin is single threaded except under special configuration for long running requests). With S3 (or any cloud storage solution), it's as simple as another HTTP request to a static resource - your app doesn't even have to know about it!

Comment: totally - leave the processes alone when it comes to static assets.